# Qt 5, Undo/Redo for every QTextBrowser in QTabWidget

Tags: qt, undo-redo, qtabwidget, qtextbrowser

I want to create multitab text and html editor .I ecountered the problem : i need to implement undo/redo operation for each text browser individually .But the operations are applied to all windows at oncee. How can i fix it ?

Comment: only trigger the operation on the current\specified tab.

Comment: @UmNyobe <code> QTextEdit* currentEdit = qobject_cast<QTextBrowser*>(tabWidget->widget(tabWidget->currentIndex())); </code> This is the best way to get current text field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `QTextEdit`, you can enable undo redo by setting `QTextEdit::setUndoRedoEnabled(true);`